# Running Outlook from VB with multiple email addresses

Tags: vb6, outlook, windows-xp

I am sending emails from my VB6 system and I am having problems with sending a single email to various email addresses.  The code is as follows:

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
Set oOutLookObject = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Email error. Err = " & Err & " Description = " & Err.Description
    EmailValid = "N"
    Exit Function
End If
Set oEmailItem = oOutLookObject.CreateItem(0)
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Email error. Err = " & Err & " Description = " & Err.Description
    EmailValid = "N"
    Exit Function
End If
With oEmailItem
    .Recipients.Add (SMRecipients)
    .Subject = SMSubject
    .Importance = IMPORTANCENORMAL
    .Body = SMBody
    For i = 1 To 10
        If RTrim(SMAttach(i)) <> "" Then
            .attachments.Add SMAttach(1)    'i)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    .send
End With
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Email error. Err = " & Err & " Description = " & Err.Description
    EmailValid = "N"
    Exit Function
End If
'''   .Attachments.Add ("c:\temp\test2.txt")
Set oOutLookObject = Nothing
```

I have set SMRecipients to a single email address and it is fine but when I add more addresses seperated by semicolons or spaces it only sends to the original address.

My system runs under XP.

Another point is that it use to find the addresses in the Outlook Address book and where they wetre not specific enough it would display the matching addresses for selection of the correct one.  It no longer does this.

Comment: This Q seems more appropriate for SO.

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, see the [FAQ]; I have flagged it for migration to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mac: Just pass the semicolon delimited email addresses to `.To`, `.Cc` or `.Bcc` properties of `oEmailItem`. Something like `"User <email@server.com>; Another User <more@server.com>"` is ok too.

Answer (score 1):

When using `.Recipients.Add()`, you need to split the recipients yourself, passing each one to `.Add()`.

```
Dim RecipientList() As String
Dim RecipientString As String
Recipients = Split(SMRecipients, ";")
For Each RecipientString in Recipients
  .Recipients.Add RecipientString
Next
```